# Объясните значение Connect by, dual, level

Tags: oracle, sql

Объясните значение Connect by, dual, level в oracle.
Подсознательно понимаю что происходит, но хотелось бы увидеть четкое определение.

Comment: А чёткие определения в документации оракла не прочитать? Вы уж уточните - или Вы хотите чтобы Вам значение разъяснили, или определение за Вас нашли. Это же не секретные данные какие-то :-)

Answer (score 1):

Например,
[Иерархические запросы в Оракл.](http://khpi-iip.mipk.kharkiv.edu/library/extent/dbms/sql/35.html)